# White space in HTML button which can't be removed and only shows up on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css

This is how it looks like (there is a white space at the right side of the search button):

[image]

And this the output CSS in a webkit browser:

```
button {
background: url(../images/search-button-mobile.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 5px;
right: 0;
width: 28px;
height: 28px;
}

div#header_search input#search-button {
background: url(../images/search-button.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
border-color: #72A329;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
float: left;
width: 73px;
height: 29px;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
searchui.css:258
button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-appearance: button;
}
searchui.css:729
input, textarea {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
searchui.css:247
button, input {
line-height: normal;
}
searchui.css:237
button, input, select, textarea {
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
searchui.css:59
body, button, input, select, textarea {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #888;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"] ::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
padding: 1px 6px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"] ::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
-webkit-box-align: center;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
color: buttontext;
padding: 2px 6px 3px;
border: 2px outset buttonface;
background-color: buttonface;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
-webkit-appearance: push-button;
white-space: pre;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
padding: 1px;
background-color: white;
border: 2px inset;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex {
margin: 0em;
font: -webkit-small-control;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: -webkit-auto;
}
Pseudo ::selection element
searchui.css:73
::selection {
background: #FE57A1;
color: white;
text-shadow: none;
}
Inherited from div#header_search
searchui.css:509
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
}
Inherited from div#header
searchui.css:509
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
}
Inherited from div#container
searchui.css:509
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
}
Inherited from body.listTabActive.have-results
searchui.css:531
body {
line-height: 1;
}
searchui.css:509
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
}
searchui.css:59
body, button, input, select, textarea {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #888;
}
searchui.css:48
body {
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.231;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header_search">
<input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="搜尋餐廳或美食">
<input id="search-button" value="搜尋" name="search-button" type="submit">
</div>
```

I have no idea where is that white space at the right side of the button coming from. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Show your HTML, please. i have the same issue with Chrome-browser within an inpu element.

Comment: @ckuetbach Ok added the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, since you didn't give CSS for the `DIV#header_search` and the `input#searchbox`. But based on borders' width and color, I think the white space is not at the right side of the `input#search-button`, but rather inside the input itself.

Also, there might be some kind of overlay: I think we can see the right border of the `#searchbox` behind the `#search-button`. Is this intended? If not, this might be an important clue.

Browsers might interpret HTML and CSS differently. I don't know anything about iPhone behavior, but you can check the common display/compatibility issues:

- Try without carriage return or any white space in your HTML code between the tags. Browsers might show then, inserting unexpected white spaces, vertically and/or horizontally.
- The `float:left` property seems unnecessary with the `position:absolute`. You might want to remove it, this property can easily cause positioning and size issues.
- It's possible that iPhone browser displays button-typed inputs differently. The value is supposed to be shown on the button, and maybe the `text-indent:-9999px` hack isn't working properly here. It might need additional tweaks. If this is your problem and you can't solve it with pure CSS, try to put the default button somewhere it can't be seen, and replace the `input[type="submit"]` by any other tag that will be shown properly on all browsers.
- Browsers calculate element sizes quite differently. They may or may not include such things as padding, margin, border. I suggest you check elements' width and left offset by trying different settings.

I don't think you're still searching for a solution. Please tell us if you found out where the problem came from and how to solve it.